# Search log module not capturing the search keyword from a custom module

Tags: search

I have a custom module for apache solr search for a particular taxonomy term - it does some custom search operations.

I want to log these search keywords to be included in search log results. Can you help me with that?

I tried adding [hook_search_info()](https://api.drupal.org/hook_search_info) in my code with standard definition - as search log module picks up data from this hook - below is the code I have added. Please help if I am adding wrong code or some other configuration needs to be done.

Also, added this module in search log configuration page to log

```
function modulename_search_info() {
  return array(
    'title' => 'Content',
    'path' => 'node',
    'conditions_callback' => 'callback_search_conditions',
  );
}
```